# Root user 'access is denied' error

Tags: root, oracle

i started to install oracle 11gR2 edition on Ubuntu 13.04 and the last step i must start this command

```
cd  /home/user/Desktop/Oracle11g/

./runInstaller
```

there is  'access is denied' error.
i have same error with root user.Help me this is the last step

Comment: Try `sudo ./runInstaller` instead. Ubuntu uses `sudo` to gain admin privileges.

Comment: maybe `chmod 744 runInstaller` helps, because runInstaller must be executable

Comment: i try sudo ./runInstaller and there is "command not found error"

Comment: i tried "chmod 744 runInstaller" but there is still "access is denied error"

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -al runInstaller` in your question?

Comment: "-rwxrwxrwx 1 kdemir kdemir 3226 Ağu 15  2009 runInstaller"

Comment: as root cd /home/kdemir/Desktop/Oracle11g/, then as user kdemir in that same directory: ./runInstaller

Comment: i try and that error "line 97: /home/kdemir/Desktop/Oracle11g/database/install/.oui: Permission denied"

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I download oracle installer and unzipped the file on windows 7 laptop. And copied that to Ubuntu. So that is the problem cause. Dont unzip file with windows 7. İf you want to use a file with Ubuntu unzip them in ubuntu OS computer...

Comment: unzipping them in Windows probably broke the default permissions in the files. also and I might be wrong about this, zip format doesn't support Linux permissions, so I would suggest downloading different formats